# Is there a Haskell IMAP library that works with TLS?

Tags: haskell, imap

HaskellNet seems to be the only available IMAP client library for Haskell, but it doesn't seem to support TLS connections, which is necessary for accessing Gmail's IMAP servers. Are there any alternative Haskell libraries or workarounds?

Comment: Not sure if you would consider this an actual solution, but it looks like the [imapget](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/imapget) package uses HaskellNet to fetch from Gmail. It looks like the author uses some of his own SSL code.

Comment: Just FYI: TLS should NEVER be part of another protocol. It should be its own layer, between the protocol and the protocol below, because modularity saves a lot of duplicate work. So if anyone reads this, avoid luddite “techies” telling you how https, imaps, and whatevers include TLS, because those are badly misdesigned by incompetent people from the commercial world driven to monolithism by an anti-social dog-eat-dog culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [imapget on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/imapget).  It gets around this limitation by creating a proxy port.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to dredge up quite an old post here, but I came across this thread when I had the same issue a while back, and have since written a library which adds SSL/TLS support to HaskellNet.  It makes use of another library, connection, which I don't think existed at the time this question was originally posted, and which made adding TLS support significantly easier than it used to be.  You can find it here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNet-SSL

Hopefully this will be of some use to anybody else who stumbles upon this thread looking for information about connecting to gmail accounts.  In fact, for gmail specifically, there is sample code for connecting to their IMAP/SMTP servers [in the repository](https://github.com/dpwright/HaskellNet-SSL/blob/master/examples/gmail.hs).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like new library appeared since your last post: [imap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/imap): An efficient IMAP client library, with SSL and streaming.